# Как узнать что сработала функция die()

Tags: php

Мысль следующая... Допустим есть регулярное выражение которое проверяет адресную строку

```
if(preg_match('/[^-a-z0-9_.\/]/', $this->Request))
{
   //если есть плохой символ то
   die();
}
```

Как узнать что сработала функция die() типа как:

```
if(die())
{
   //но тут и ежу понятно что так баян)
}
```

Зачем нужно?

Отлавливливаем что сработала функция die() и запускаем функцию которая пишит в лог где, когда и почему была вызвана функция die();

Конкретно хочу знать, возможно или нет? Спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сделай так, что бы функция die() возвращала значение (true, false) и его проверяй

Comment: Сделал ответом! Так и поступлю. Что-то недодумался, вечерело уже наверное)

Comment: Чувак, функция die убивает процесс :))) Труп она тебе вернет :)))) 
Хм... ответ Dem - правдивый :))))

Answer (score 4):

Можно обойтись без `die()`.

Для того чтобы вести лог ошибок, можно установить соответствующие обработчики через функции [`set_error_handler()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php) и [`register_shutdown_function()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.register-shutdown-function.php)

Comment: Я бы сказал: "нужно обойтись без `die()"

Answer (score 3):

die может выводить сообщение и сразу останавливает генерацию страницы

```
die('some message');
```

Answer (score 3):

Проще и правильнее сделать что-то подобное:

```
define('LOGFILE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/epitaph.txt');
function epitaph($text) {
  if (!$l = @fopen(LOGFILE, 'a+')) exit;
  fwrite($l, '> '.date('Y.m.d H:i:s').': '.$text."\n");
  fclose($l);
  exit;
}

if (/* ... */) epitaph('Error #1 in '.__FILE__.' line '.__LINE__);
```

Еще можно юзать [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.debug-backtrace.php).

Сомневаюсь, что можно переопределить функцию `die()`

Comment: Спасибо, есть пара интересных строк.

Answer (score 0):

Вот что бы не городить огород - объявляем функцию:

```
function my_die($param = '')
{
    // записываем в лог
    die($param);
}
```

ищем & заменяем во всям проекте die на my_die и радуемся жизни.

Answer (score -1):

Можно. Вот пример:

```
$link = mysql_connect($slc_dbhost,$slc_dbuser,$slc_dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
```

То есть если ошибка подключения, то вызываем функцию пхп. Можно указать собственную функцию.